# Git rebase with local feature branch

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase, branching-and-merging

haven't found an answer to my specific case and couldn't come up with a solution with the existing ones.

So, I have a repository which uses two remote branches:

```
master
dev
```

On my computer they are synced with two local branches and I have another local branch, which isn't synced with a remote:

```
master -> origin master
dev -> origin dev
feature
```

Now, the preferred workflow would be to develop on the local *feature* branch and if finished, commit and push to origin *dev*. If it is accepted, then subsequently integrated into the *master*. This way both branches should be, more or less, identical and up-to-date. 
However, now I'm confronted with the following situation:

```
master    ...o=o=o=o=o=o=o=o=o=o=o=o
                 |
dev       ...o=o=o=o=o
                     |
feature   ...o=o=o=o=o=o
```

In prose: *Master* is nine commits ahead of *dev* (a colleague of mine pushed directly onto the master), *dev* is two commits ahead of *master* and the local *feature* branch is one commit ahead of *dev*, whereas both *dev* and *feature* are missing the commits from *master*.

How can I get back on track now, without breaking the history?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is merging "feature" in "dev" and then merging/rebasing "dev" on "mastet" an option?

Comment: @AndreaCarraro I'm not entirely sure. I'd like to rebase, however I need to push the changes back to the remote branches, because my colleagues also need it. So I shouldn't do that, right?

Answer (score 2):

RomainVALERI solution it's OK, by like he has written: "it won't look pretty". You can use rebase. Thanks rebase your history will be cleaner.

```
git checkout dev
git rebase master
--> resolve potential conflicts 
git checkout feature
git rebase dev
--> resolve potential conflicts
```

Your situation right now look like this (I change commits to "m" and "n" to show better how rebase works):

```
master    ...o=o=o=m=m=m=m=m=m=m=m=m
                 |
dev       ...o=o=o=d=d
```

After rebase your branch will looks like this:

```
master    ...o=o=o=m=m=m=m=m=m=m=m=m
                 |
dev       ...o=o=o=m=m=m=m=m=m=m=m=m=d=d
```

Git will rewind not pushed commits (named d) to the top.

"M" commits will not changed, will have the same sha-1, but "d" will changed.

Comment: But that will rewrite my entire history so that I won't be able to push it, won't it?

Comment: No, it will rewrite only some commits. I edit my answer to show you how it work.

Comment: Alright, am I getting it right that if I'm rebasing my *local* changes on *dev* on top of the *remote* changes on *master*, I'm not messing up the history, because only the SHA's for the *dev* commits will change, which haven't been pushed yet?

Comment: One question: you said that _dev is two commits ahead of master_. That two commits are already pushed?

Comment: Yes, so dev has some unique commits, master doesn't have and vice versa.

Comment: So if that 2 latest commits on `dev` are pushed and there are not on master,  you can't do rebase. Rebase will changed their sha's. In that case you should do what RomainVALERI wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first merge `master` into `dev` and resolve potential conflicts to get `dev` up-to-date, then merge `dev` into `feature` to the same effect.

At this point `feature` is the "most advanced" tip, and it's quite straightforward to merge back : `feature`>>>`dev` then `dev`>>>`master`.

Then again, you seemed to prefer a rebase strategy for your repo, and if so, my solution won't look pretty.